# Constant Push of SQL Server data to MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database, connection

Is there a way I can have a constant update of my SQL Server data going to a MySQL database?

Comment: There probably is, but can you describe your setup in more detail?

Comment: Definitely, The easiest way I can think of describing this, is that all my main content comes down and is stored in a SQL database. I want to push that info to a MySQL database and use it for validation purposes only. The reason for the MySQL is we are using PHP and running a custom CMS that connects only to MySQL. So user data needs to be brought over from the Source and displayed so the USER can be validated properly and also allow for further development projects.

Comment: How constant does it need to be? Real time? Or can you get away with a small time delay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exactly how big of a delay is acceptable will more or less guide the *type* of solution you use.

- **Updates need to be (near) real-time**:  you need to either (a) have whatever is pushing the data to MSSQL also push to MySQL at the same time, or (b) [use replication](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?26,9548,57244) to do it
- **Updates can be delayed a while**:  then instead of trying to replicate things you can make it into an ETL process, where you have a few options, the best of which is probably using SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS) where you can design ETL packages to do the push any way you want

Comment: Third alternative, use triggers to put records ina staging table and then run a job every X number of minutes to move those records. Do not try to use a trigger to push directly to a mySQL database as it can cause issues if that database goes down.
But I like your alternatives best.